# Any Idea how to create a windows application and its windows service? Like antivirus. .NET

Tags: service

I need to create a window application that runs through a service as well as the antivirus that have their service and application, I need to send error messages to the user, I have the service but I do not know how to send error messages. I do not know how to create antivirus, if someone has any idea how to do that, I'll be grateful

Comment: Welcome StackOverflow. While asking the question you should also mention what you tried. If you are stuck at step 0 itself please google and follow some tutorial.

Comment: Then you should do some work on your side and update that in your question. Like how and what you searched online to get the direction for this. What you are doing simply gives the idea that you have not tried to do any base work and simply put up the question. Post your findings along with the question

Comment: Bro by simply saying that you do not have any idea that is why not proceeding is discouraging yourself. If you yourself are not interested in helping yourself then expecting others to help may not be very good idea.

Comment: For example if you search for "creating windows application as service" you get https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.100).aspx. I get your problem is not exactly the problem statement but where and what to search. In that case you should mention what you searched

Comment: and this http://www.howtogeek.com/50786/using-srvstart-to-run-any-application-as-a-windows-service/

Comment: That is good, my suggestion will be added it as part of your question. Basically you need to show your own enthusiasm rather than getting angry. A good way to go will be keep updating your question and adding what you have found. This way other folks unlike me who know will show interest

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help and how it will help but posting this as answer to give a direction for your searches.[Google - creating windows application as service](https://www.google.com/search?q=creating%20windows%20application%20as%20service&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Above google search gives ways to setup a program as service

[How to Run Any Program as a Background Service in Windows](http://www.howtogeek.com/50786/using-srvstart-to-run-any-application-as-a-windows-service/)
[Walkthrough: Creating a Windows Service Application in the Component Designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx)